# Light fixture has no ground on it

Tags: electrical

Putting a light fixture up but there is no ground wire on it, there is a ground comeing from box in celling , how would I hook this up

Peterborough Ontario Canada

Comment: Can you post a photo of the fixture, or include the make and model?

Answer (score 2):

If the light fixture has no exposed metal parts then it doesn't need a gorund wire.

Many new fixtures are all plastic and hence are inherintly safe since there is nothing that can become energized.

Just coil the ground wire up and leave it in the box.